# Properly Aggregate datas in RDLC

Tags: expression, aggregate, rdlc

I have this Data from the DataSet which I then display in the tablix on an rdlc report viewer. This datas have redundant `CUSTOMER NM`(which is group by 2's) that is why I want it to be blank display on the 2nd display.

I am using this expression to hide the even rows that are displayed in the tablix which is under the column of `CUSTOMER NM`:

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!CUSTOM_NM.Value,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 2, Fields!CUSTOM_NM.Value, "")
```

But the result is not what I am expecting.
As you can see on the image below, it seems that the data's are being grouped as per same `CUSTOM NM`. and the `CUSTOM NM` that is set to `""` are the next same rows of `CUSTOM NM`. I color the groups so you can see them properly.

[image]

My expected result would look like this image below

[image]

Anyone knows where I am doing wrong or miss something. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

You may use hideDuplicate Property under properly list for that particular textbox in tablix.

for that you need to set textbox's HideDuplicates property to the containing group name.

Comment: This is quite embarrassing, I solved my problem already. 
I did change something on my expression. 

The correct expression would be then `=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!CUSTOM_NM.Value,Count,Nothing) Mod 2, Fields!CUSTOM_NM.Value, "")`

Instead of using `CountDistinct` I use `Count`. Maybe this was the reason its causing to Blank the next set of data. Anyway thnx for the reply.